# Socialite google works on localhost only, not production

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

I have facebook and google login using socialite, facebook works but google I've only managed to get to work locally, so for example locally the url is http://dev.thesite.com and in production the url is https://thesite.com, that's the only difference, however when trying to log in with google in production i always get the invalidState exception

I've noticed that when I get the `InvalidStateException`, under `environment and details` I have:

```
REQUEST_URI  "/login/google/callback?state=EoWyQabT7M6wFKbPWyNJ5UD1jpLaID8v0RylvWll&code=4%2FuAFENTN62cKi-HJH7MLDFnrn8LtALjwi0zpd1Fmx688A6Vj_uSMDPk-p5EtQl_GayYKtcasjInfPjL6gfSImto8&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&session_state=84bdbb33a08cc16bbaf7584540c9b97deca3dafb..5d5c&prompt=consent"

QUERY_STRING    ""
```

So the `QUERY_STRING` is empty for some reason.

My .htaccess files redirects all requests to https, I believe that maybe some .htaccess setting can solve this.

Comment: might be related to - [https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/389](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/389)

Answer (score -1):

go to `config/session.php` and set (without www)

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', yourdomain.com),
```

and in console

```
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Delete all cookies from browser

Comment: `cache:clear` is the for the cache store, it has nothing to do with the configuration cache